# Rails: guard does not use zeus if model file changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, guard, zeus

Trying to use guard-rspec with zeus:

```
# Gemfile (the meaning part)
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'shoulda'
end

# Guardfile
guard 'rspec', zeus: true, bundler: false do
  # watch...
end
```

All gems have latest versions. Zeus and guard start smoothly without any issues.

When start guard all specs running with zeus speed.
But when changing rails model file guard runs corresponding spec slowly same as without zeus.
Wierd and confusing thing: when changing model spec, helper spec or even helper itself guard runs corresponding specs quickly again.
Cucumber features always run speedy no matter of file initiator.

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: I've post issue with detailed explanation what happens to zeus repo https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/273

 - no feedback yet